# Controlling a loop using counter in Anible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to gather a list of interfaces from a switch that are not part of a port channel. I am trying to control the position of the list using a counter so that I can then specify the key so I can see the value but I am not successfully doing it.

But when I use the counter i get list object has no attribute .

```
- name: Check for port-channel config in the Ethernet
  nxos_command:
    commands: sh run int {{ item }} | include channel-group
  register: output
  with_items: "{{ ethernet }}"

- name: Trim down conf output
  set_fact:
    int_config: "{{ output['results'] }}"

- debug:
    msg:
      - "The counter is {{ counter | int }}"
      - "Found interface with channgel-group, interface {{ item }}"
   name: show the results
   loop: "{{ int_config[counter] }}"
   loop_control:
     index_var: counter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was trying to do, see below.

```
- name: Check for port-channel config in the Ethernet
  nxos_command:
    commands: sh run int {{ item }} | include channel-group
  register: output
  with_items: "{{ ethernet }}"

- debug:
    var=output

- name: Trim down conf output
  set_fact:
    int_config: "{{ output['results'] }}"


- name: Create list of int that will be removed
  set_fact:
    cleaned_ethernet: "{{ cleaned_ethernet | reject('search', item['item']) | list }}"
  loop: "{{ int_config }}"
  when: item['stdout'][0] != ''

- debug:
    var=cleaned_ethernet

- name: Configure each Ethernet port not in a Po with MTU of 9216
  nxos_interface:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    mtu: 9216
  with_items: "{{ cleaned_ethernet }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
- debug:
    msg: "Counter: {{ item|int }} Interface: {{ int_config[item] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, int_config|length)|list }}"
```

This task with the data below

```
int_config:
  - abc
  - def
  - ghi
```

gives

```
"msg": "Counter: 0 Interface: abc"
"msg": "Counter: 1 Interface: def"
"msg": "Counter: 2 Interface: ghi"
```